# Updating changing xhr URL's in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

For my cypress test cases, I'm using `cy.intercept` to wait for a certain `xhr` requests. However, the xhr URL will change frequently.

For example,

```js
cy.intercept('/text/1000/text').as('getText');
```

could be `/text/2001/text'` the following week.

How can I have it so that those 4 numeric characters change automatically instead of needing manual input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Arguments)...

> #### Arguments
>
> url (string | RegExp)

The URL can be a regular expression. Try something like

```js
cy.intercept(/\/text\/\d{4}\/text$/).as('getText')
```